# JavaFX2.2 (stable) ignores set properties for "socksProxyHost" and "socksProxyPort"?

Tags: java, proxy, javafx-2, socks

First, I would like to mention that I also had this problem when **2.2** was still beta (forced me to revert back to **2.1.1**).

Installed **JavaSE 7u6** today (comes bundled with **JavaFX 2.2** *stable*). **NetBeans** was 
able to automatically detect the `Default JavaFX Platform`.

Created a new `JavaFX Application` project (tried the **FXML** derivative with the same result as well). Tried this piece of code:

```
package javafxapplication;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class JavaFXApplication extends Application 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
        System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "9050");

        try
        {
            URLConnection conn = new URL("http://www.wikipedia.org").openConnection();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

And it works. Without spewing an error that no connection could be made due to bad socks proxy settings (there is **nothing** running on that port on my machine). These properties are silently ignored and the connection occurs **directly**. Is this a bug? I've tested this on 2 machines running **Win7 x64**. Does **not** happen on **2.1.1**.

Comment: URLConnection is pure java class, I don't think it has any connection with JavaFX. (so added java tag to your question)

Comment: Sergei, that's the weird part - somehow it's interconnected. After the installation of JavaFX 2.2 the aforementioned properties have no effect on my machine. However, when reverted back to 2.1.1 - everything works. I have tested this already on 3 machines runing Win7 x64. I can only draw one conclusion from this that 2.2 has something to do with it.. Also, this is not a plain JavaSE project, but a JavaFX one (that could explain things a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX 2.2 introduced support for system proxy (see http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-21705).

It may interfere with socks proxy settings. You can try remove your system proxy or try to add next to JVM options: `-Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true`

Comment: Sergei, I have updated my OP with full source code now. Apart from using **JVM** options, is there anything else that could be done **inside** the src code? Thank you.

Comment: I filed an issue http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24517 on that matter. You may want to subscribe to see developer's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, Sergei. Signed up for jira tracking on the issue.